# Why does (int)(2/0.9) = 2?

Tags: java, casting, arithmeticexception

I put this into java and I was given the result 2. Was wondering why it isn't an ArithmeticException, as shouldn't (int)(2/0.9) turn into 2/0. All help is appreciated.

Comment: 0.9 is a float, so 2 is promoted (or interpreted as) a float, and then the division takes place.  The *result* is cast to int.

Comment: Oh so the division occurs before the cast?

Comment: @MatthewFenel Of course. `(2/0.9)` is in parentheses no?

Comment: Yes.  The parenthesis around `2/0.9` even make that explicit.  `2/(int)0.9` should give you the result you are....expecting?

Comment: Oh ok thanks! This is just for computer science lol.

Comment: parenthesis are 'slight' older than computer science, have few hundred years and well understood sense

Comment: @zzxyz actually `0.9` is a *double*, not a float.

Comment: @Bohemian ah sorry I was using float loosely as in 'floating point' which is probably not a smart thing to do in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is

```
(int) (2 / 0.9)
```

So the `int`-**cast** is only applied to the **result** **after** computing `2 / 0.9`. Now `2 / 0.9` divides an `int` by a `double` value. In such a case the `int` will also be interpreted as `double` (`2.0` in this case). The result is thus like

```
2.0 / 0.9 = 2.22...
```

This process is known as **numeric promotion** (it uses **widening primitive conversion** here [JLS§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)). From [JLS§5.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6):

> A *numeric promotion* is a process by which, given an arithmetic operator and its argument expressions, the arguments are converted to an inferred target type `T`. `T` is chosen during **promotion** such that **each argument** expression **can be converted to** `T` and the arithmetic **operation is defined** for values of type `T`.

After that you **cast** to `int` which will round the value to the next lower integer, `2` in this case. Thus the result is `2`.

---

What you expected would be the result of an expression like

```
2 / (int) 0.9
// or more explicit:
2 / ((int) 0.9)
```

which first casts the `0.9` to an `int` before dividing. In this case you would correctly get

```
2 / 0
```

yielding the expected `ArithmeticException`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you very much :)